# lock used and there is no looping still, Exceptions System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, collections, invalidoperationexception

I have gone through similar looking questions, where answers are suggesting to use `lock` and not to modify List inside of `foreach` loop on the same collection, I have already taken care of these two.

I have globally available `List<Object>` and there are two different threads which are reading and writing in the list respectively.

To avoid race condition, I have used `Lock` at both (reading[using linq] and writing). 
and also I'm creating local copy, modify it and restore that copy to main copy (to reduce time of lock)

> I guess while creating a local copy, it is having reference of main
>   copy and thus main copy is being updated out side of lock too. Correct
>   me here!

Including similar code for reference,

```
    private void UpdateList(List<Object> newList)
    {
       List<Object> localCopyOfList;
       lock(m_lockObj) //again a global object for locking
       {
          //I suspect it is reference type's problem here
          localCopyOfList = m_globalCopyOfList; 
       }
       foreach(Object obj in newList)
       {
          localCopyOfList.Add(obj);
       }
       lock(m_lockObj)
       {
          m_globalCopyOfList = localCopyOfList; 
       }
   }
```

and for reading, I have method like,

```
private int GetTotalCount()
{
   List<Object> localCopyOfList;
   lock(m_lockObj) //again a global object for locking
   {
      localCopyOfList = m_globalCopyOfList; 
   }
   //On following line I'm getting this exception
   //Exceptions System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   return localCopyOfList.where(x => x.status == true).Count;
}
```

Comment: Your code example is clearly made up and not real code; there is no declaration of `lockCopyOfList` shown, and you probably meant `localCopyOfList`. That said, your guess about reference types is not far off course; you're not making a copy of the list, you're only making a copy of the reference. It's the same list. If you really want a copy, try `m_globalCopyOfList.ToList()`. Note that, likewise, the `lock` statements protect only the _variable_ `m_globalCopyOfList`, and not the contents of the list itself.

Comment: The code, `localCopyOfList = m_globalCopyOfList` does *not* create a local copy of the list. It creates a local pointer to the *same* list. This might work better: `localCopyOfList = m_globalCopyOfList.ToList()` (but note that the objects inside the list are also references and still point to the same as those in the original list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I suspect it is reference type's problem here.

Yes. You are not creating a new list, you just copy the reference to the same list.

In order to create a new list based on existing values, you can use [List copy constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<Object> localCopyOfList;
lock(m_lockObj) //again a global object for locking
{
    //I suspect it is reference type's problem here
    localCopyOfList = new List<Object>(m_globalCopyOfList); 
}
foreach(Object obj in newList)
{
    lockCopyOfList.Add(obj);
}
lock(m_lockObj)
{
    m_globalCopyOfList = localCopyOfList; 
}
```

Keep in mind that `localCopyOfList` does not reference to the same collection as `m_globalCopyOfList` anymore, but its elements do.

Answer (score 0):

You are merely copying the reference to the same list in your lock. They are therefore the same instance.  You need to create a new list for local and copy the contents from the global list into it, inside your lock.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any locking is required.

```
private void UpdateList(List<Object> newList)
{
  //only read operation on global list, adding  items only to local list  
  newList.AddRange(m_globalCopyOfList);  
  //reference assignment is atomic
  m_globalCopyOfList = newList;
}

private int GetTotalCount()
{
   //reference assignment is atomic
   var localCopyOfList = m_globalCopyOfList; 
   //if UpdateList method is called anytime during below operation, 
   //m_globalCopyOfList ref will point to new list, localCopyOfList will not 
   //be touched.  
return localCopyOfList.where(x => x.status == true).Count;
}
```

@Amit I made demo program with 250 tasks calling updatelist and getlist each. I did not get any exception or data loss. Not sure if I am missing anything but check code below

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {

        var obj = new Demo();
        var t = Enumerable.Range(1, 500)
        .Select((x, index) => Task.Run<int>(() => index %2 == 0 
                                            ? obj.UpdateList(new List<object>() { new { status = true } }) 
                                            : obj.GetTotalCount())).ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(t);
        Console.Write(obj.GetTotalCount());
        Console.ReadLine();
        return 1;
    }

    public class Demo
    {
        private List<Object> m_globalCopyOfList { get; set; }
        public Demo() {
            m_globalCopyOfList = new List<object>();
        }
        public int UpdateList(List<Object> newList)
        {
            //only read operation on global list, adding  items only to local list  
            newList.AddRange(m_globalCopyOfList);
            //reference assignment is atomic
            m_globalCopyOfList = newList;
            return 1;
        }

        public int GetTotalCount()
        {
            //reference assignment is atomic
            var localCopyOfList = m_globalCopyOfList;
            //if UpdateList method is called anytime during below operation, 
            //m_globalCopyOfList ref will point to new list, localCopyOfList will not 
            //be touched.
            Console.WriteLine("Current count " + localCopyOfList.Count); 
            return localCopyOfList.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They both functionality (reading and writing) are in different threads which are quite a frequent thus to be in safe side `Lock` is needed, However I have tried your suggested answer at first place before asking here. It was causing the same exception.

Comment: Amit I made demo program with 250 tasks calling UpdateList and GetTotalCount each. I did not get any exception. Not sure if I am missing anything but check code above